# How to insert data to a template after render ? (django)

Tags: python, django, templates, render

I am making a decorator to insert verification code into a template. The scenario is the following :

```
@insert_verification
def my_view(request):
    # View code here...
    return render(request, 'myapp/index.html', {"foo": "bar"},
        content_type="application/xhtml+xml")


def insert_verification(func):
    def wrapped(request):
        res = func(request)
        if type(res) == HttpResponse:
            # add a verification code to the response
            # just something like this : res.add({"verification": 'xxxxx'})
            # and varification can fill in the template
        return res
    return wrapped
```

I use the following template:

```
{% block main %}
<fieldset>
    <legend>{{ title }}</legend>
    <form method="post"{% if form.is_multipart %} enctype="multipart/form-data"{% endif %}>

    {% fields_for form %}
    <input type="hidden" value="{{varification}}" >
    <div class="form-actions">
        <input class="btn btn-primary btn-large" type="submit" value="{{ title }}">
    </div>
    </form>
</fieldset>
{% endblock %}
```

It seems I should render a template twice with different dictionary. But I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Isn't this the whole point of form validation and the django form system? Are you sure you can't just put the verification in a forms.py clean method?

Comment: why did you need to check `if type(res) == HttpResponse:`. all views must return an HttpResponse else django will throw error. right???

Comment: @suhail Oh,the code is planed to raise exception when misuse of `insert_verification` function happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the better approach will be to implement your [context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors) to add `verification` context variable to the template contexts.

For example:

verification_context_processor.py

```
def add_verification(request):
    #get verification code
    ctx = {'verification': 'xxxxx'}

    #you can also check what path it is like
    #if request.path.contains('/someparticularurl/'):
    #    add verification 

    return ctx
```

In settings.py, update

```
import django.conf.global_settings as DEFAULT_SETTINGS

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = DEFAULT_SETTINGS.TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS + (
    'custom_context_processors.add_verification',
      )
```

You view should use [`RequestContext`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#django.template.RequestContext) while rendering the response.

```
def my_view(request):
    # View code here...
    return render_to_response(request, 'myapp/index.html', {"foo": "bar"},
                 context_instance=RequestContext(request)
                 )
```

Comment: actually `render_to_response` is an old format. use `render(request, 'myapp/index.html', {"foo": "bar"})`

Comment: `context processors` seems a global processor.Why I want to use decorator is that I can just add a verification without any other change when a new view need verification.

Comment: If use `context processors`,I should alter `add_verification` function everytime when adding a new view need verification,so is there anyway can reduce complexity?

Comment: @Mithril It depends upon how do you get verification code. If it does not matter what view it is. It will be added in template context for each view. The template will just use it if it wants to or need not use it.